# Monitor a remote IBM Websphere with VisualVM and JMX

Tags: websphere, jmx, visualvm

I am trying to monitor a remote IBM WAS with VisualVM but I can't connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable JMX on the IBM Websphere open the WebSphere administrative console and:
    navigate to: Server -> Server Types -> WebSphere application servers ->[SERVER_NAME]

Expand Java and Process Management and click Process definition
    Click Java Virtual Machine
    In the Generic JVM arguments field append the following properties:

```
-Djavax.management.builder.initial= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=XX.228.75.XX
```

Restart the server

[image]

When the server starts, open VisualVM and add a new Remote Connection:
In the connection field, put the server host and the port previously configured, for instance 1099.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks to Jamie Craane's Blog: http://jcraane.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/monitoring-ibm-jvm-with-visualvm.html This solution did not work for me because I was connecting to a remote server and It is neccessary to add the property -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=XX.228.75.XX